# Travis CI not triggering upon GitHub organization repository change

Tags: github, travis-ci

On GitHub, I have both an account (etat-de-geneve) and an organization (republique-et-canton-de-geneve).

On Travis, I created an account (@etat-de-geneve).

When I push a commit on a repository of the GitHub **account** (etat-de-geneve), the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/etat-de-geneve/jours-feries/blob/master/.travis.yml) file fires the Travis CI, as expected.

However, when I push a commit on a repository of the GitHub **organization** (republique-et-canton-de-geneve), the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/republique-et-canton-de-geneve/jours-feries/blob/master/.travis.yml) file **fails to fire the Travis CI**.

Configuration:

- In my Travis account, the GitHub organization is
  defined as an authorized organization.
- In my GitHub organization, my GitHub account is Owner (= Admin) for the
  repository.

[image]
Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might stumble on the same issue: in Travis > Settings, I had performed "Manage repositories on GitHub" for my *account*. The solution was: performing "Manage repositories on GitHub" for my *organization*.